# Adding ticks to PolarPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks

I want to add some number ticks to a unit circle in `PolarPlot` like the one attached, but how can I do it?

```
PolarPlot[Circle[], {t, 0, 1}, PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
     PolarTicks -> {Drop[Table[i, {i, 2*Pi, 0, -Pi/5}], 1], Automatic}]
```

[image: The effect I want]

Comment: So, you have a working code that uses custom ticks, but you are not willing to experiment with it and see if you can solve the problem on your own? I am sorry, but you have to show some effort.

Comment: If all else fails, read the documentation for [`PolarTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolarTicks.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PolarPlot[1, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 1}, 
 PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
 PolarTicks -> 
  Evaluate[{#, If[# == 0, "0/1", ToString[Round[#/(2 Pi), 0.1]]]} & /@
     Range[0, 9/5 Pi, 2 Pi/10]]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, the unit circle is within the boundary of the plot. Do you know how to make the boundary of the plot to be the boundary of the unit circle?

Comment: I updated the code. Added the PolarAxesOrigin option that takes care of your concern